# How to show hidden fields when using Display Suite module to manage display?

Tags: display-suite, entities

I'm an addicted user of the fantastic [Display Suite module](http://drupal.org/project/ds) to manage the displays of content types. But it sometime happens that after changing the layout of a content type (e.g. Two stacked column) some field doesn't show up. This happened with the location node field solved in this [issue](http://drupal.org/node/1125170) by its author.

Now, I'm using the [Ubercart Auction module](http://drupal.org/project/uc_auction) which create a content type called 'product'. When you add a product you fill some auction settings. Then when you load the node it shows a form with auction info and links. This one:

[image: This one]

So far so good. Now if I go to admin/structure/types/manage/product/display and change the Layout to **Two stacked column** I get no field to show this form. I get all other fields (body, title, images,...) but no one to show that auction form.

I know that the field is a **form** but I don't know how make available as field.

How can I solve this?

**@lance**: 
Maybe I should show where are the auction setting in the node. Look this picture:

[image]

Comment: Is this field probably a view? If yes, try to add the view via View-Field.

Comment: Not sure if I fully understand, but if the field is a view then it should be listed in admin/structure/views, rigth? I don't see any auction related view. Please look the lines I added at the bottom of the question

Comment: Right, probably a deactivated view which you can activate?

Comment: there are: uc_product, uc_customers and uc_order views (all of them enabled) but nothing related to an auction table form.

Comment: I know that the field is a **form** but I don't know how make available as field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to enable Extra Fields, which allows Display Suite to manage module-created fields.
[image]

Comment: I already had it enabled. Should I add a field where it sas "Enter fields line by line, where each line is a combination of entity type, bundle and field name" ? Which one? I don't know the name of the field. I only know that it is a form.

Comment: I think node|your_product_content_type|uc_auction will do it